# HTML - Press enter in text field set focus on other text field

Tags: html

I want to create a form in HTML with 3 textfield and 1 button. In load the page or refreshed the txt1 textfield would be automatically focused, when pressing enter key the txt2 will be focused and if pressed enter again the txt3 will be focused and when pressed enter again it will submit.

is there somebody knows it how to do it? please help... code example below...

thanks...

```html
<form name="form1" action="filename.php" method="post">
text1: <input type="text" name="txt1" autofocus><br>
text2: <input type="text" name="txt2"><br>
text3: <input type="text" name="txt3><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: when I run the code above and then press tab it will go to/focus second textfield and when I press the tab it will go to/focus third textfield I want also the same action when pressing enter...

Comment: This can be made with JQuery, I think this can't be made with HTML + CSS

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a combination of HTML and jQuery:

HTML:

```
<form name="form1" action="filename.php" method="post">
    text1: <input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1" autofocus><br>
    text2: <input type="text" id="txt2" name="txt2"><br>
    text3: <input type="text" id="txt3" name="txt3"><br>
        <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').on('keypress', function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {           
            switch($(this).attr('id')){
                case 'txt1':
                    $('#txt2').focus();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    break;
                case 'txt2':
                    $('#txt3').focus();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    break;
            }         
        }
    });
});
```

Demo:  https://jsfiddle.net/s4r6a1qo/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function runScript(e) {
    //See notes about 'which' and 'key'
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {        
        document.getElementById("scriptBox2").focus();
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
<input id="scriptBox" type="text" onkeypress="return runScript(event)" />
<input id="scriptBox2" type="text" />
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.